# Alternatives to SuperSized

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

I'm looking for alternatives to Supersized. I'm currently using version 3.0 to show some rotating background images and found two problems on Internet Explorer.

1. The transicion is far from smooth, and is very slow. On Chrome and Firefox this works ok.
2. Some times, the background images are vertically enlarged and deformed.

Does anyone knows an alternative, or a tweak to fix those problems?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any slider and float it behind the content of the page using `z-index`. I like [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) when I'm just sliding images, and [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) when I need to slide a div or ul with arbitrary content.

The element you're applying `z-index` to must be `position: relative;` or `position: absolute`. One thing to note about `position: absolute;` is that it will position the element with respect to the first parent element that is `position: relative;` or `position: absolute`. That may sound confusing, so how about an example:

Put your slider inside `<body>` and wrap it in a div:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Your slider divs/imgs/ul -->
    </div>
    <div class="rest-of-page">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

Then some css:

```
/* Position .container relative to body (not really needed, just an example) */
body { position: relative; }

/* Float slider behind content of page, expanding to width/height of document
 * and use z-index of -1 to place it behind actual page content. */
.container { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0%; 
    left: 50%; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    z-index: -1; 
}

/* Float the actual page content above slider using z-index of 0 */
.rest-of-page { position: relative; z-index: 0; }
```

And that should do it. Normally you have to define a width for your slider images, but with some fiddling I think you can get it working. In my own projects I've been centering the slider to the page, not taking up the entire background, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can give what you need. But you can take a look at [SuperBGImage](http://dev.andreaseberhard.de/jquery/superbgimage/). Actually it's inspired by supersized but with some convenient improvements